# How to fix the issue in connecting allwinner Android tablet for USB debugging on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, 14.04, android

I have issues in connecting Android tablet for USB debugging on Ubuntu 14.04. I have followed the tutorial from

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1228508

```
karthikeyan@spark:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 023: ID 1f3a:1009  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

1f3a is the vendor id. I have added the same in rules file.

```
#Allwinner 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1F3A", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev", OWNER="karthikeyan"
```

Line on the /etc/fstab

```
#mount point for allwinner tablet
mtpfs /media/allwinner fuse user,noauto,allow_other 0 0
```

When I connect the device as MTP, it mounts a drive. But it throws error as below.

```
Device 0 (VID=1f3a and PID=1007) is UNKNOWN.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying     again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
inep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): Resource temporarily unavailable
outep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): Resource temporarily unavailable
libusb_open() failed!: Resource temporarily unavailable
LIBMTP PANIC: Could not init USB on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
```

ADB doesn't show any device connected.

```
adb devices
```

Comment: That link is for unsupported and outdated kernels.

Comment: So what will work now? can you find any issue in what I did?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your usb vendor id to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini. Worked for me. Example:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE. 
0x1f3a
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem simply `Ctl` `Alt` `T` and type in `sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs`

When you finish installing, you can now safely plug the device in with little to no issue.

[Source](http://www.unixmen.com/connect-your-android-galaxy-tablet-to-ubuntu-via-usb/)

Comment: The drive is mounted already and I am able to access file system inside that. I just want to enable the usb debugging.

Comment: Usb debugging is enabled via the device itself.
Settings, developer options, under debugging section there is that option you would enable that.

Comment: Yes. It is enabled in device. But adb doesn't detect it.

Comment: ok since that is your issue your better off http://stackoverflow.com/  to better assist you I did find some answers but your device is unknown, so look around there.